# htacces regex to the following link

Tags: regex, .htaccess

[http://local.domain.ro/index.php?/login/login-*-login-*-login-*-produs-*-horn-metalic](http://local.domain.ro/index.php?/login/login-_-login-_-login-_-produs-_-horn-metalic)

I want to redirect it, permanent, in htacces to the following link:

http://local.domain.ro/produs/horn-metalic

I've searched for this topic, and try some answers but it doesn't help me.

**EDIT**

This is what I am trying:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^index.php?/login/login-_-login-_-login-_-produs-_-$     [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/produs$             /produs/$1     [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: You can find some information at [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html), and [Setting up a permanent 301 redirect via .htaccess](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess).

Comment: I'll try those links. thank you!

Comment: And here is one more: [mod_rewrite based on query string parameters](http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html). Once you get it up and running, and still have trouble, please come back to update this question.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.php\?/login/login-_-login-_-login-_-([^-]+)-_-([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [NE,NC,R,L]
```

Comment: hey! it seems that this part 'login-_- ', sometimes repeat more than 3 or 4 times, or is there just once, and in that case this condition doesn't apply...